# Friction and materials

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

If someone had the ability to manipulate friction, could they give solid objects elastic properties, like causing the ground to become bouncy by decreasing the internal friction of molecules between each other, or even things like steel beams? I'm not familiar with all of the mechanics and physics involved, and it would be a great help if someone could enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The technique of making rubber more springy by milling into it varying amounts of mineral oil is well-known, as is making plastics soft and bendable by blending the resin with special oils called plasticizers. But these effects have nothing to do with friction as such; both are due to preventing (weak) intermolecular bonds from forming between adjacent polymer strands through the use of oily additives.

These techniques work with polymers, but not with metals.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding solids are solids because the molecules that make them up are bound. It has nothing to do with friction. Even if you had the ability to weaken these bonds it wouldn't make the material elastic, it would just make the material sloppy like a liquid. Elasticity is simply the tendency for something to return to its natural shape when all forces are removed from it.